# Convert 12-hour format to 24-hour format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, hour

How to convert 12-hour format to 24-hour format in `DateTime` format.

I already tried to convert the `DateTime` to string (24-hour format) and convert it back to `Datetime` format but it is not working.

Comment: .Net DateTime struct does not store display format. you need to use `ToString()` with a format provider to display it in whatever format you want.

Comment: Would you please send your try?

Comment: Please Send your try and also your expected input and output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using extension methods are also good idea.

```
public static class MyExtensionClass
{
    public static string ToFormat12h(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd, hh:mm:ss tt");
    }

    public static string ToFormat24h(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd, HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Then you can use these 2 methods as following:

```
var dtNow = DateTime.Now;

var h12Format = dtNow.ToFormat12h();    // "2016/05/22, 10:28:00 PM"
var h24Format = dtNow.ToFormat24h();    // "2016/05/22, 22:28:00"
```

Comment: How to get only hours in 12-hour format in such case?

Comment: @ThamaraiT, just play with the string format ;). You may use `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: You mean, to get hours we need to convert the datetime to string, right?

Comment: @ThamaraiT, it's another overload for `ToString`. For `DateTime` format you can use `ToString` method to give the desired format for the date-time.

Answer (score 9):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123); 

dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); //12 HOUR FORMAT
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");    //24 HOUR FORMAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code.

```
string time = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
String militaryDate = dt.ToString("HH:mm:sstt");
Console.Write(militaryDate);
```